# Using an 'or' where clause with a projection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, where-clause, projection

I am new to mongodb so forgive me if this question has an obvious answer or if it's a little unclear but I have searched for hours now and I have no idea why this isn't working. I want to get all users(collection name) with a red shirt or is over the age of 20 which I can get, but I only want to print out the users id and name.

Example of document in collection:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId(hy65fi6152g8off589992y),
"id" : 02451,
"age" : 20,
"shirt" : "red",
"name" : "bob"}
```

Query I thought would work:

```
db.users.find({
$or:[
{"shirt" : "red"}, {"age" : {$gt:20}}
]
}
{id : 1, name: 1, _id: 0}
)
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `}` and `{id : 1, name: 1, _id: 0}`.
Try: `db.users.find({ $or:[ {"shirt" : "red"}, {"age" : {$gt:20}} ] }, {id : 1, name: 1, _id: 0})`

Comment: Thank you, i'ts often the simple things you miss.